# How does SBT decide between JAR entries or directory entries in fullClasspath and internalDependencyClasspath?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have one project which shows directory entries when I type

> show internalDependencyClasspath

whilst the other project shows JAR file entries.

Moreover, when I type

> show fullClasspath

the first project shows JAR entries taken from `managedClasspath` plus directory entries taken from `internalDependencyClasspath`. The second project shows all entries as JAR files.

Also, I've noticed that the second project packages classes immediately after compilation, whilst the first project doesn't do that.

How does SBT decide if `internalDependencyClasspath` shows directory entries or JAR entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to see only JARs in `internalDependencyClasspath` (and also in `fullClasspath`), put this setting below into your `build.sbt`:

> exportJars := true